# Bootstrap 4 card/panel with image left of header and title

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I thought what I'm trying to do would be pretty easy to do but I just can't make it work.

I tried to do pull-left on bootstrap cards and panels and it's not working the way I want it to...

Here is a picture of what I'd like to acheive

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Hk2.png)

Heres code that almost works

```
<div class="card text-center" *ngFor="let event of eventActivities">
    <div class="card-header pull-left">
        <img src="..." alt="">

        Title </div>
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Description</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">BUTTON</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There are a few different ways you could do this. Here's one way using the  `flex-row` and `flex-wrap` utility classes to change the layout of elements inside the card...

https://codeply.com/go/l1KAQtjjbA

```
   <div class="card flex-row flex-wrap">
        <div class="card-header border-0">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="card-block px-2">
            <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Description</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">BUTTON</a>
        </div>
        <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="card-footer w-100 text-muted">
            FOOTER
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's another approach using the grid...

```
  <div class="card">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <img src="//placehold.it/200" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card-block px-2">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Description</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">BUTTON</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer w-100 text-muted">
            Footer stating cats are CUTE little animals
        </div>
  </div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/l1KAQtjjbA

I'm not sure why you have `text-center` as nothing it centered in the desired example image.

Comment: I get it now.  The `flex-row` in the `card` div runs the Header, Body, and Footer horizontally.  You added `flex-wrap` to the `card` div and `w-100` to the `card-footer` to push the Footer so far out as to have it wrap/fall vertically below the Header and Body.  Then the only thing left to do was fix the extra-thick border below the Header, which you did so in the `card-header` div by adding `border-bottom-0`.  Very Clever!  FYI:  I removed the `<div class="w-100"></div>` and it ran the same without it.  Thanks for the codeply example!

Comment: if the description were too long, the paragraph will break the layout..i just tested it

Comment: @aswzen I believe this is why Zim added the alternate example.  If you use `row` and `col` then you you could move your `card-header` into the 1st `col` and `card-block` into the 2nd `col` and the longer description will still appear horizontally next to the header and will look identical to the one with a shorter description without the `row` and `col`.

Comment: The image lost the position when use a large content in `p`. For better results use a `col-md-2` and `img-fluid` class into content of card.

Comment: @e-info128 - so you think my answer deserves a downvote for an unrelated issue?

Comment: I love that you changed the footer text!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the class `pull-left` is now `float-left` in Bootstrap version 4.