# grid/list toggle view with Bootstrap 4 Cards

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a grid/list view using bootstrap 4 cards.

```
<div class="well well-sm">
    <strong>Display:</strong>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="#" id="list" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="fas fa-list-ul"></span>List</a> 
        <a href="#" id="grid" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="fas fa-th-large"></span>Grid</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

the jquery:

```
$('#list').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.card-deck').addClass('list-group-item');
  $('.card-deck').removeClass('grid-group-item');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('#grid').removeClass('active');
});

$('#grid').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.card-deck').removeClass('list-group-item');
  $('#list').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.card-deck').addClass('grid-group-item');

});
```

i've got code from another post: [Bootstrap 4 card/panel with image left of header and title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141874/bootstrap-4-card-panel-with-image-left-of-header-and-title)

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card-block px-2">
                <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Description</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">BUTTON</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer w-100 text-muted">

    </div>
</div>
```

but what i want is, when clicking on grid, the view changes to a stacked card block like so:

```
<div class="card-deck>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can this be done? **its important for it to work with bootstrap 4.**

thanks for your help.

Nabi

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would add an `id` to each of your containers like a class or an id 'grid-view' and 'list-view':

```
<div class="card" id="grid-view">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card-block px-2">
                <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Description</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">BUTTON</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer w-100 text-muted">

    </div>
</div>
```

And

```
<div class="card-deck" id="list-view">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I would use the `hide()` and `show()` functions in the Js file:

```
$('#list').click(function(event){
    ...
    $('#grid-view').hide();
    $('#list-view').show();
});

$('#grid').click(function(event){
   ...
    $('#grid-view').show();
    $('#list-view').hide();
});
```

Make sure you hide one of the views at the initialization of your page.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. i have over 200 products that i want to display and adding the 2 div views would add a lot of weight to the page, is there a way to do this by changing the css and adding classes?

Comment: @NabiArshad I don't really know how to answer to that. Personally (and because I don't have the answer :) ) I prefer to take the time it takes to load everything firstly. That's a choice. But think about it, if you want to load the corresponding html only at a click, it would means you will have to reload at every click your html, which could also cost time and weight.

Comment: yes i understand what you mean, but surely there has to be another way like here: https://codepen.io/bootstrapped/pen/RRBdbm. but with bs4 cards?